# How do I stop animals like wolves, eagles, bear from starvation?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I tried to put the wolves in pastures but that didn't work. I tried butchering animals to provide meat for them and still it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure they need to eat? AFAIK only animals with the [GRAZER] tag or able to speak need to eat.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have to agree with @Pierre-Luc.
After doing some easy googling for you, I looked at the raw-files for [Wolf](http://www.dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Wolf/raw), [Eagle](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Eagle/raw) and [Bear](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Bear), and they all lack the [STANDARD_GRAZER] token. The wiki page about [Black bears](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Black_bear) even states specifically: 
`Bears in general lack the [GRAZER] tag which means they don't require pastures. This makes them an ideal component of a meat industry.`

Did these animals die from wounds, or perhaps some other reason?

Answer (score 2):

Animals stored in cages, as long as they are "non-grazing" (for example wolves), can stay alive without being fed. See:

http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/v0.34:Captured_creatures

for details on caged creatures.